# Error - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, jslint

Im getting 2 errors in this for-loop. Both are giving me error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

The error is because of the two rows marked "//Here" below:

```
var f="";

var printRange =function(rangeStart,rangeStop){
    for (var a3=rangeStart; rangeStop>=a3; a3++) 
        rangeStop >=a3 && (f+=a3+",");                   //Here
        a3==rangeStop && (f+=a3);                    //Here
        return f.substr(0,f.length-1);
};

ANSWER = printRange(28,47);
```

I can't figure out why they are not correct. I can't see what I've done wrong.

Comment: @rageandqq LOL. I am surprised this compiles, but I guess not in all browsers.

Comment: You are missing some if statements. It is also not really clear what you want to achieve. It is better to explain what you want to achieve and then say what is going wrong and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Additonal advice:

Use ' instead of ". Always, realy always create a block with curly braces for if, for, .... Name variables appropiate to give them a meaning. Use spaces and indention to format your code. Makes it more readable.

Read "JavaScript, the good parts" from Crockford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition in an if block:

```
if (rangeStop >=a3) f += a3+",";  
if (a3==rangeStop) f += a3;
```

Also, the `for` block is missing curly braces and the indentation is ambiguous so I'm not sure what you want/expect there. It's best to add them.